# Questions about Golang's fyne toolkit

Tags: go, user-interface, toolkit, fyne

I recently wanted to study fyne toolkit and read the Getting Started documentation on fyne.io and proceeded with the procedure on Prerequisites.
Initially, Msys2 terminal entered the command as indicated in the document and thinks the installation is complete.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5mSZ.png)

In Goland imported fyne through the go get and go install commands and also used example code.
After that, I ran main.go, but it seemed to collide between packages like the pictures below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3u2p.png)

Therefore, when I watched the issue of github or used gpt, I found that the C compiler was not properly installed. I definitely thought I installed the C compiler properly.

First, I looked at the system environment variables.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEg0M.png)

And I looked at whether the conditions were working properly through fyne setup. Then I discovered the problems.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDt3x.png)

I don't know what the hell's wrong with it.
Seek help with stackOverFlow.

I can't find any information about this in my country.

Answer (score 1):

Following the instructions sets up the MSYS2 terminal. You will need to run your build commands there and it should work.

To configure other terminals or IDEs you will need to copy the PATH and other environments from the MSYS2 configuration once it is working.